# Android Layout LIstView/TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a ListView which contains a list but it does not look so nice.

My view looks like this:

[image: my view]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

My Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="persistence.RecordsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recordListView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recordListEmptyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/no_records"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any my Kotlin file:

```
class RecordsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_records)

        this.recordListView.emptyView = recordListEmptyView


    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val records = RecordDAO(this).findAll()

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,records)

        this.recordListView.adapter = adapter
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.records,menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_add -> {
                val i = Intent(this, RecordFormActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                true
            }

            R.id.action_stats -> {
                val i = Intent(this, RecordFormActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                true
            }

            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

}
```

And second question, how do I accomplish that it says there are no performances if the list is empty? Do I have to do a If-clause and have to check if list is empty on my own ?

Comment: At the moment you're showing the `toString()` method of the objects returned by `RecordDAO(this).findAll()`. Can you please your code for those objects?

Comment: What do you exactly mean, yopu mean the RecardDAO class?

Comment: The class of the object returned in the list by the `findAll()` method. Sorry stupid question actually. I can see it output in the textview. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,records)
```

In top snippet, you use a system list item layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` that's been used by the `ListView` adapter, this represent a simple `TextView` with the appearance you see in the before photo.

In order to deviate from this simple list item, you need to create your own customized list item. To do that, create `list_item.xml` layout, and add a `TextView`, and customized its attributes like paddings, colors, text size ...etc as you want.

Here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Then establish your adapter with the new list item layout

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.layout.list_item,records)
```

> And second question, how do I accomplish that it says there are no performances if the list is empty? Do I have to do a If-clause and have to check if list is empty on my own ?

Yes you've to check if the size of the records items fed to the list adapter is 0 or greater than that, and then toggle the `ListView` & a `TextView` visibility accordingly with [View `visibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#setvisibility)

Answer (score 0):

Map your `Record` objects to what you want displayed. eg.

```kotlin
val records = RecordDAO(this).findAll().map {
    "${it.moduleName} ${it.moduleNum} (%${it.noteInProzent} ${it.creditPoints}crp)"
}

val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,records)
```

That way you're only displaying the strings you want.

Then to show something else when the list is empty you could do something like the following.

```kotlin
val records = val records = RecordDAO(this).findAll()
if (records.isEmpty() {
    recordListView.visibility = View.GONE
    recordListEmptyView.visibility = View.VISIBILITY
} else {
    // show your records
}
```